# Android Cursor over Generic list of business objects?

Tags: android, database

In .NET land I would normally query the database and populate a generic List kind of collection. Then the app would use this.

In Android land I have been reading about DB access and use in apps. Why do most of the docs show the use of a cursor and use of constants to access it? Is this to save on resources perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this to save on resources perhaps?

Exactly. + performance.
The general rule is to avoid creating objects w/o necessity as you are limited on memory, cpu power (and resulting battery life) and garbage collection is rather expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cursor for your adapter. Android is driven by listadatpers such as SimpleCursorAdapter. Using constant is a pro for design technique.