# Android - Database vs Business logic for frequent updates

Tags: android, sqlite, business-logic

I am developing an application where I use at least 5 Countdown timer with different initial time. I load the initial time together with other information from a Sqlite db and use an Activity to show the user the state of these timers. I need to populate a ListView with timers informations every seconds. Usually the initial time can be 2 or 3 hour long so I developed a Service for the business logic and a CountdownTimer for each timer.

Do you think is a good idea binding the GUI directly with the db or it's better to use some business logic objects as middle-man?

I read in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033540/android-cursor-over-generic-list-of-business-objects) that in Android most of the docs show the binding of database and GUI. They answered that this approach is preferable for performance reasons but I think that's not my case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finished. At last I decided to bind the GUI to my business logic objects and building this objects from the database only before the timer is started. Every timer tick I change only the business logic objects in memory. I realized this way I need to update my db fewer times, only when the timer is stuck. I think this way my application is faster.