# Cursor Binding vs Object list Binding in android

Tags: android

I need some help with listview binding. I have read that the most effective way to use a listview binded to a datasource is to use a cursor which speaks directly to sqlite. I start my project using this method but I'm not able to face a critical for my application issue.

I need to change values of the binded list but those changes doesn't affect my database until user press save button. In c# I can do this in many ways like datatable or bindingsource objects.

For example, my app has a list with products with their prices. I want to change prices through a popup window which open from context menu. When the popup window close I need to display the new price in listview but I haven't save it into database yet. Finally when I have change prices of all products I want to press save button and update my database using a transaction.

Is there any way to succeed something like this using cursors for binding or I have to use lists of custom class objects?

Comment: This question is repeated, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033540/android-cursor-over-generic-list-of-business-objects

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using custom data objects would be a good way doing it:

1. read your products from database into a `list` of custom `Product` objects, then use `ArrayAdapter` to display the data in the `ListView`
2. after changing price on a product call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter to redraw the list with new values
3. when save button pressed - use the list of the `Products` to generate database updates in a single transaction